# Android notification action pendingIntent triggers receiver but receiver intent extras are empty

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

In my app on a device running 'Pie' I trigger a notification with a try again action when a job (yigit/android-priority-jobqueue) fails. the action button "Try Again" calls the broadcast receiver onReceive as expected and the action name is correct but the intent extras are null. The channels have been created also.

The notification code is as follows:

```
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    int notificationId = 123;

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent contentPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    Intent tryAgainIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
    tryAgainIntent.setAction(TRY_AGAIN_ACTION);
    tryAgainIntent.putExtra(Extras.POST_ID, postId);
    PendingIntent tryAgainPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, tryAgainIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), "com.example.android.GENERAL_NOTIFICATIONS")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo)
            .setContentTitle("Post sync failed")
            .setContentText("Syncing the post failed")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText("Syncing the post failed, try again?"))
            .setContentIntent(contentPendingIntent)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_logo, "Try Again", tryAgainPendingIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    // send the notification
    manager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
```

My receiver is as follows:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

        if(TRY_AGAIN_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            // gets here fine

            Long postId = intent.getLongExtra(Extras.POST_ID, -1);
            // postId is always -1

            Long postId = (Long) extras.get(Extras.POST_ID);
            // postId is always -1 here also
        }
    }
}
```

My manifest entry is:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.MyReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="TRY_AGAIN_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I'm stumped as to why it all works except the intent extras in the receiver are null, any suggestions?

Comment: You are using Firebase Notification ?

Comment: in `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` use different `requestCode`

Comment: @SanjayChauhan no its a custom system.

Comment: @pskink thank you, I missed that, that was all it was.

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: @pskink Can you explain why using a different `requestCode` solves the problem?